# Sort HashMap data by keys

Tags: rust

Cross referencing to [Rust forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/sort-hashmap-data-by-keys/37095?u=hajsf), I'm generating a [HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee2d232e787774e1ba626a42552ed4b0) / below code.
How can I sort the generated result `map` based on the `keys`, in my case based on `Dimension, Location`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone)]
struct Dimension {
    item: String,
    color: String,
    size: String,
    part_number: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Delivery {
    variant: Dimension,
    location: String,
    quantity: i32,
}

pub fn main() {
    let data = vec![
        Delivery {
            variant: Dimension {item: String::from("A"),
                                color: String::from("B"),
                                size: String::from("C"),
                                part_number: String::from("D")},
            location: String::from("L"),
            quantity: 10,
        },
        Delivery {
            variant: Dimension {item: String::from("A"),
                                color: String::from("B"),
                                size: String::from("C"),
                                part_number: String::from("D")},
            location: String::from("L2"),
            quantity: 3,
        },        
        Delivery {
            variant: Dimension {item: String::from("A"),
                                color: String::from("B"),
                                size: String::from("C"),
                                part_number: String::from("D1")},
            location: String::from("L"),
            quantity: 5,
        }, 
        Delivery {
            variant: Dimension {item: String::from("A"),
                                color: String::from("B"),
                                size: String::from("C"),
                                part_number: String::from("D")},
            location: String::from("L"),
            quantity: 5,
        },        
    ];

    // The keys of this map will be groups
    let mut map: HashMap<(Dimension, String), Delivery> = HashMap::new();
    for d in data {
        let record = map
            .entry((d.variant.clone(), d.location.clone()))
            .or_insert(Delivery {
                variant: d.variant.clone(),
                location: d.location.clone(),
                quantity: 0,
            });
        record.quantity += d.quantity;
    }

    for (variant, delivery) in &map {
        println!("{:?} has {:?}", variant, delivery.quantity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`itertools` crate](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.sorted) extends the standard iterator so that it can be sorted:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use itertools::Itertools;  // itertools = "0.8"

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone, Ord, PartialOrd)]
struct Dimension {
    item: String,
    color: String,
    size: String,
    part_number: String,
}

fn main() {
    // ...

    for key in map.keys().sorted() {
        println!("{:?} has {:?}", key, map[key].quantity);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html), which is a sorted map by itself:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone, Ord, PartialOrd)]
struct Dimension {
    item: String,
    color: String,
    size: String,
    part_number: String
}

fn main() {
    // ...

    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    for d in data {
        let record = map
            .entry((d.variant.clone(), d.location.clone()))
            .or_insert(Delivery {
                variant: d.variant.clone(),
                location: d.location.clone(),
                quantity: 0,
            });
        record.quantity += d.quantity;
    }

    for (variant, delivery) in &map {
        println!("{:?} has {:?}", variant, delivery.quantity);
    }
}
```